How to get changed and added properties with diff?
I'm trying to compare two objects and get only the properties that have changed or been added in the second object. I'm using the diff library in Node.js, but I'm dont know how to do it .
const Diff = require('diff');

var lhs = {
  name: 'my object',
  description: 'it\'s an object!',
  details: {
    it: 'has',
    an: 'array',
    with: ['a', 'few', 'elements']
  }
};
 
var rhs = {
  name: 'new',
  description: 'it\'s an object!',
  profile: "admin",
  details: {
    it: 'has',
    an: 'array',
    with: ['a', 'few', 'littleChange']
  }
};

Diff.diffJson(lhs, rhs);

console.log(rhs);

Current Output:
{
    name: 'new',
    description: "it's an object!",
    profile: 'admin',
    details: { it: 'has', an: 'array', with: [ 'a', 'few', 'littleChange' ] }
  }
  
ExpectedOutPut:

{
    name: 'new',
    profile: 'admin',
    details: { it: 'has', an: 'array', with: [ 'a', 'few', 'littleChange' ] }
  }

I want to also Include the entire parent object if any of its nested properties have changed.
How can I modify my code to achieve this expected output? Is there a better way to do this comparison and extraction of changes?

Does the documentation really specify that the second object passed to diffJson will be modified?  Or does it specify that diffJson returns information about the differences?  What documentation/example are you referencing for this?
